# Command-line SCEP client that works with Active Directory NDES

Tags: active-directory

Doing a Google search I found several command-line SCEP clients that I can download and build. Can someone recommend one that will work with Active Directory's NDES (Network Device Enrollment Service) (either Linux or Windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSCEP (Simple SCEP client for Unix) client at http://www.klake.org/~jt/sscep/ ended up working nicely.